# "if S were to do" vs "if S did"

Tags: subjunctives

I learnt that you use "were to do" when you use the subjunctive mood to express the future.

ex) What would you do if the world **were to come** to an end tomorrow?

Does that mean the following two sentences are wrong?

1. What would you do if the world **came** to an end tomorrow?
2. What would you do if the world **would come** to an end tomorrow?

=========

In an ordinary "if" clause, you use the simple present tense whether you mention the present or the future, don't you.

- I'll give it back to you if this wallet is really yours. (present)
- I'll stay home if it rains tomorrow. (future)

And I know that the sentence below is correct.

- I would buy a car if I had enough money. (unreal present)

And I also know that the sentence below is correct.

- What would you do if the world **were to come** to an end tomorrow? (unreal future)

What I want to know is whether the two sentences below are correct or not.

1. What would you do if the world **came** to an end tomorrow?
2. What would you do if the world **would come** to an end tomorrow?

I'd like to know whether you have to use "were to" instead of the simple past or "would" when you mention an unreal future.

Comment: Both of your sentences use the subjunctive *irrealis mood* to show that it's a hypothetical situation, so there's no difference there. The difference is that the first one uses a simple tense, but the second one uses "*be to*" future, in this case in the subjunctive mood because it's unreal, which is "were to". Are you asking about the difference between a simple tense and "be to" to indicate future?

Comment: I know that you use "be to do" to indicate future, such as "The government is to increase tax."  I'd like to know if you if you need to use "were to do" to refer to the future in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: "...came..." *is* the subjunctive form of "come". It has nothing to do with "be to". "Were to do" = be to + "do" + subjunctive. "Did" = "do" + subjunctive. It's incorrect correct to use "would" in an "if" clause in that context because it would also be incorrect to use "will" in an "if" clause in that context. It's got nothing to do with subjunctive.

Comment: Your comment is off the point.  I'm NOT asking about the difference between "be to come" and "come".  I'm asking whether you need to use "be to" to indicate an unreal future.  What I want to know is whether the two sentences are grammatically correct or not, and whether they can convey the same meaning as the first one.

Comment: No, you don't need "be to" to describe an unreal future. "*If I **won** the lottery...*" is an example of the unreal expressed without "be to". Sentence 1 is correct. Sentence 2 is wrong for reasons I've already described. I'm confused why you think "be to" might be necessary to describe unreal future since your level of English is obviously high enough to know unreal conditionals, which do not require "be to".

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I believe you are a native speaker of English and you may not understand why I need to ask these kinds of questions because they seem too obvious to you.  However, it is almost impossible for us non-native speakers to figure out what is correct and what is not without asking native speakers.  English learners very often stumble where native speakers would never find any barriers.

Comment: When the textbook says "you use 'were to' to express an unreal future," there is no way we can tell whether it means you MUST use it or you CAN use it.  You may think I can look for example sentences on the Internet, but it's very difficult to find a good example pertaining to the question, and even if you find one, there is no telling if it's really grammatically correct since it may have been written by a non-native speaker.  I hope you understand how difficult it is for us non-native speakers to learn minor differences that native speakers would never even pay any attention to.

Comment: I understand what it's like because I've taught English as a Second Language for eighteen years, and I studied five foreign languages for more years than that. So yeah, I get it.